# How to query and display user firstname from User model using a Model that has morphTo()

Tags: database, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.1

I know the question is a bit hard to understand. But, I promise it is not once you read this: I'm creating a simple application to create products, stores and users reviews in a single table called reviews. So, in this case, I'm using the [Polymorphic Relation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

Below are my database table migration:

This is my users table migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username')->nullable();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This is my reviews table migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('body')->nullable();
        $table->integer('reviewable_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('reviewable_type')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps(); //contains the review date etc..
    });
}
```

Here is the products table migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('category')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('price')->nullable(); // Product price
        $table->string('product_photo_path')->default('image/default_product_photo.jpg')->nullable(); //add one first
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

For my models:
in my Review.php model, I have this relationship:

```
  public function reviewable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();

}
```

in my User.php model I have this relationship:

```
  public function reviews()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Review', 'reviewable');
}
```

in my Product.php model I have this relationship (same as User model):

```
  public function reviews()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Review', 'reviewable');
}
```

I'm able to list out all product reviews made by users in one page but how do I display name of user who made the comment using the $reviews variable.

Example, this is my ReviewController.php where I have this function to query all reviews:

```
public function index()
{
    $reviews = Review::all();
    return view('reviews.index')->with('reviews', $reviews);
}
```

Then in the reviews.index.blade.php

I can simply call

```
   @foreach($reviews as $review)
    {{$review->body }}
   @endforeach
```

this will list out all reviews made by users. So, the question is, how do I display user first_name using the $review variable? I tried below but it doesn't work:

```
   @foreach($reviews as $review)
    {{$review->users->first_name}} //Not working
   @endforeach
```

I thought that I need to put an extra relationship on the Review model like below so that I can do like this review->users->first_name;

```
    public function users()
   {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
   }
```

but that doesn't work. So, how do I define the relationship here where the Review model is already defined as Polymorphic relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that was a silly mistake right there. Instead of

```
   public function users()
   {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
   }
```

i changed to

```
    public function users()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
  }
```

Solved the problem.